# How to do a query with different composite key?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have tables A and B, these tables have different compound keys
table A has COD_E, NRO_S and table B has COD_E, NRO_S, COD_MOT, COD_TIPATE

I need different fields from the tables and I can't do the query, send me an error in Oracle
SQL command did not complete successfully

Error Code:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
SELECT T1.COD_E,T1.NRO_S, T1.ROL, T1.OFI, T2.COD_MOT , T2.COD_TIPATE
FROM A AS T1
INNER JOIN B AS T2
ON T1.COD_E = T2.COD_E
AND T1.NRO_S = T2.NRO_S;
```

I  expect T1.COD_E,T1.NRO_S, T1.ROL, T1.OFI, T2.COD_MOT , T2.COD_TIPATE from tables

thanks!!

Comment: Try removing the semicolon `;` from the end.

Comment: And remove `AS` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support `AS` for table alias, but only for column:

```
SELECT T1.COD_E,T1.NRO_S, T1.ROL, T1.OFI, T2.COD_MOT , T2.COD_TIPATE
FROM A T1
INNER JOIN B T2
ON T1.COD_E = T2.COD_E
AND T1.NRO_S = T2.NRO_S;
```

Comment: thnks , i feel so dumb, again thnks so much